# Possibility to navigation when app is in background

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I would like to ask about possibility to modify backstack and navigate to previous screen when app is not in foreground with Jetpack Compose approach (without fragments)

My case:

App1 opens list apps screen and then opens App2 (App1 is the custom launcher)
App2 finishes work, send broadcast and finish.
App 1 receives broadcast and then should navigate back from apps list to main screen.
The problem is that navigation only works when app return to foreground. It cause that navigateUp action is performed only after displaying last screen and it looks like last screen shows aproximately 0,5-1s and then navigateUp is fired.

Expected result is displaying main screen when App2 finished.

I tried to call navController.navigateUp() directly in viewmodel but navigate action is executed only after UI draw is finished.

Do you know any possibility or workaround to achieve it without fragments? With fragments here was possibility to call navigateUp when Fragment called onPause (before drawing UI).